# Is a res file the same as a rc file?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I was looking at a resource file properties dialog box, and I noticed it was using a .res for want it command line strings, specifically, in this section.

```
Resource File Name    |        $(IntDir)%(Filename).res
```

So I am confused. Is a res file the complied output from a rc file?

I'm using VS2013 Express Ed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this

1. Create a resource-definition script (.rc file) that describes the resources used by your application.
2. Compile the script with RC. For more information, see `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381055(v=vs.85).aspx.`
3. Link the compiled resource (.res) file into the application's executable file with your linker.

i.e After compilation using rc you will get .res file.

for more Info visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380599(v=vs.85).aspx

Hope it helps you.